# Specific tab open on load

Tags: css, tabs

I'm using these tabs on a page to keep all the information needed on one page.
My question is, when I link from another page, would it be possible to open a specific tab on load? What should I look for? Hope You can help me out here.

Thank you.

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab_how" checked />
     <label for="tab_how">Something here</label>
      <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">

      </div>
</li>

<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab_support" />
     <label for="tab_support">Something else here</label>
      <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">

      </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What need be a trigger for tabs? current page or page from here is linked?

Answer (score 0):

Add a name or id to you ul as anchor:

```
<ul id="target_tab" class="tabs">
```

for the link:

```
<a href="thispage.html#target_tab">Link</a>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That didn't quite do it for me. As I only have one <ul></ul> for the entire content. Do you have any idea how to work around this?

Comment: What do you mean by open? Are they hidden by default?

Comment: The first tab is the "Something Here" which has the "checked" in the end. Whick makes that tab be the first visible one. So none are hidden, but the "Something Here" is the tab open when loading the page.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you need to achieve. Is this what you are look ing for? https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/c7bb63az/

Comment: Here's a picture to demonstrate how it looks. http://i.imgur.com/cTL5zux.png?1 I should probably have linked this in the first place.

Comment: Ahh! That's nothing to do with radio buttons. Check this out https://jqueryui.com/tabs/